# Cannot run start an VM using KubeVirt with GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Currently I try to use `KubeVirt` with `GKE` cluster.

What I have done (follow the official document):

1. Create a `GKE` cluster with 3 nodes via GCP console
2. Install `kubectl` locally and connect to this cluster
3. Install `kubevirt` via `kubectl`
4. Install `virtctl` locally
5. set `debug.useEmulation` to `true`
6. create the `testvm` (follow the demo)
   All the steps above work fine.

But now I have troubles to start the vm

1. If I try to start it via `"virtctl start testvm"`, I get the following error message:

**"Error starting VirtualMachine the server has asked for the client to provide credentials"**

2. If I try to modify the VM template to set it running by default, it doesn't work either.In the `virt-launcher` pod, the compute container starts successfully but the `volumecontainerdisk` fails, with the following log:

```py
standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "permission denied"
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What is the KubeVirt (operator) version you are using?

Comment: @AnuradhaFernando I am using v0.27.0

Comment: Did you try it with the ```kubectl``` as well? i.e. 

```kubectl get vms``` then ```kubectl virt start testvm```?

Comment: I could manage to re-create the issue, looks like this is a problem with authenticating ```virtctl``` with the ```GKE``` (in my case) or the kubernetes engine. Will get back with more findings.

Comment: Dup of [Is there a way to enable nested virtualization in GKE cluster node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60750664/is-there-a-way-to-enable-nested-virtualization-in-gke-cluster-node)

Comment: @coderanger, Thank you for your attention. Not exactly same issue.  I am trying to attack it in different directions. The other question focus on whether I can use nested virtualization. This one is for the issue I encountered when try to use the emulation.

Comment: It looks like `patching` method described [here](https://kubevirt.io/labs/kubernetes/lab1) successfully changes state of the vm to `running`: `kubectl patch virtualmachine myvm --type merge -p \
    '{"spec":{"running":true}}'`. When using `./virtctl start testvm` I also get the same error message.

Comment: @mario, thank for your answer. I tried this before. It doesn't work for me. (I am not sure it is the same root reason, or due to other cause).    


When I patch the running states to the vm. The vm turns to running state and the vmi and virt-launcher pod is created but in error stage.   

When I describe the pod, the computer container works flne, but the volumecontainerdisk has error.

    
clin4@cloudshell:~ (slb-datalake-lakefront)$ kubectl logs  virt-launcher-testvm-j7dw8 volumecontainerdisk
standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "permission denied"

Comment: Keep in mind that this is merely an **emulation process** so I suppose it has its limitations and to be honest I'm not sure how it is supposed to work. For sure it is not able to emulate everything so as far as you don't have **nested virtualization** enabled you won't be able to make sure it really works and AFAIK currently it is impossible to activate it on **GCE VMs** forming the **GKE cluster**. Have you tried to test it on anything else like locally on **Minikube** ?

Comment: @mario, yes, currently I am doing an evaluation myself. I have tried the MiniKube both in local and in a GCE VM with nested virtualization enabled. Both work fine.

Comment: Same basic situation; I was able to make forward progress by enabling Basic Authentication for the GKE cluster then: `gcloud container clusters describe kubevirt --zone=$ZONE --project=$PROJECT --format=json | grep password` to get the password, and `virtctl start testvm -n default --kubeconfig=/home/jkane/.kube/config 
--username=admin --password=$PASSWORD` for virtctl stuff.  It's a horrible solution, but it works until I can find something better.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there are issues with the default GKE auth method when connecting from local to a cluster when using `gcloud container clusters get-credentials...`.

What worked for me is creating a new SA and creating a kubeconfig for it:

```
{
kubectl create sa deployer
kubectl create clusterrolebinding deployer --clusterrole cluster-admin --serviceaccount default:deployer

KUBE_DEPLOY_SECRET_NAME=`kubectl get sa deployer -o jsonpath='{.secrets[0].name}'`
KUBE_API_EP=`kubectl get ep -o jsonpath='{.items[0].subsets[0].addresses[0].ip}'`
KUBE_API_TOKEN=`kubectl get secret $KUBE_DEPLOY_SECRET_NAME -o jsonpath='{.data.token}'|base64 --decode`
KUBE_API_CA=`kubectl get secret $KUBE_DEPLOY_SECRET_NAME -o jsonpath='{.data.ca\.crt}'|base64 --decode`
echo $KUBE_API_CA > tmp.deploy.ca.crt

export KUBECONFIG=./my-new-kubeconfig
kubectl config set-cluster k8s --server=https://$KUBE_API_EP --certificate-authority=tmp.deploy.ca.crt --embed-certs=true
kubectl config set-credentials k8s-deployer --token=$KUBE_API_TOKEN
kubectl config set-context k8s --cluster k8s --user k8s-deployer
kubectl config use-context k8s

rm tmp.deploy.ca.crt
unset KUBECONFIG
}

kubectl virt start testvm --kubeconfig ./my-new-kubeconfig
```

More explanation: https://faun.pub/manually-connect-to-your-kubernetes-cluster-from-the-outside-d852346a7f0a

Answer (score 1):

You can start vm without `virtctl` by updating VM's manifest using `kubectl`

```
kubectl patch virtualmachine testvm --type merge -p '{"spec":{"running":true}}'
```