# GKE-kubevirt virtualmachineinstances-mutator.kubevirt.io issue

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to use kubevirt in google cloud platform GKE cluster.
I got to know the GKE won't support nested virtualisation so i tried below step to install kubevirt in GKE
[Is there a way to enable nested virtualization in GKE cluster node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60750664/is-there-a-way-to-enable-nested-virtualization-in-gke-cluster-node)

1. Start a GKE cluster with ubuntu/containerd, n1-standard nodes and minimum cpu of Haswell.
2. Find the template used for your new cluster, then to determine the proper source image:

gcloud compute instance-templates describe --format=json | jq ".properties.disks[0].initializeParams.sourceImage"

3. Create a copy of the source disk with nested virtualization enabled:

gcloud compute images --project $PROJECT create $NEW_IMAGE_NAME --source-image $SOURCE_IMAGE --source-image-project=$SOURCE_PROJECT --licenses "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/vm-options/global/licenses/enable-vmx"

4. Use "Create Similar" on the template for your GKE cluster. Change the boot disk to $NEW_IMAGE_NAME. You will also need to drill down to networking/alias and change the default subnet to your pod network.

5.Trigger a rolling update on the group for your GKE nodes to move them to the new template.

6. I'm able to install kubevirt and virtctl but when i try to launch basic vm using

```
kubectl apply -f https://kubevirt.io/labs/manifests/vm.yaml
```

I'm getting below error:

`Error from server (InternalError): error when creating "https://kubevirt.io/labs/manifests/vm.yaml": Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "virtualmachines-mutator.kubevirt.io": failed to call webhook: Post "https://virt-api.kubevirt.svc:443/virtualmachines-mutate?timeout=10s": context deadline exceeded`

Is there any way to debug the error.
How to make Kubevirt work in GKE.

I am trying to achieve Kubevirt in GKE

Comment: Are you running a private cluster?

Comment: Yes. We are running private cluster.@GariSingh